# jQuery attr() returns undefined for iframe element

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to get src property of iframe in order to pass new value for src onclick. I'm trying following :
Call.js

```
     jQuery(this).bind('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
                  jQuery('#frame1').ready(function(){
                  var src = jQuery('#frame1');
                  console.log(jQuery('#frame1');) //shows element
                  console.log(src.attr('src')); //undefined
                });
      });
```

call.php

```
<div id="e-call">
<div class="e-body">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="frame.php" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" id="frame1"></iframe>
</div>
```

So, basically, I got lost already. Google gives me nothing.

**EDIT**

Posted a bit wrong one, sorry

Comment: What is `new_src` supposed to be? It's not declared anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Indeed, I posted the wrong one, now this one should show the problem.
@Pointy just  new URL-source for iframe

Comment: The only times jQuery's `attr` returns `undefined` are 1) If the jQuery set you call it on is empty (no elements in it), or 2) If the first element in the set doesn't have the ilsted attribute. So apparently, whatever element matches `id="frame1"` has no `src` attribute.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thats a problem - it has. I see it in the source code. And it is not empty. It also has other attributes like width, height, all this stuff but result is always undefined. 

And I could even retrieve at least the iframe itself only through jQuery, document.getElementById was returning undefined.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). I'd wonder about it being a cross-origin problem, but a quick test says you can access the `src` attribute even if the iframe's *content* is on another origin (which makes sense, the element is in your document, not the iframe's content document).

Comment: (It probably can't be a runnable Stack Snippet, I think they disable frames. But a couple of code blocks that one can copy and paste to see the problem occur.)

Comment: *"And I could even retrieve at least the iframe itself only through jQuery, document.getElementById was returning undefined."* `getElementById` never returns `undefined`; it may return `null`. Note that jQuery **never** returns `null`, it always returns a jQuery object (but that object may be empty). If you're getting `null` from `getElementById`, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/), the canonical "not found" question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: Your update is not a [mcve]. Please read the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override your `src` with `new_src`
pass `new_src` as an arg in attr as below:

```
src.attr('src',new_src);
```

Comment: I do get it, but problem is, that I cant even get current src. Therefore this one doesnt work, because it shows that src.attr('src') is undefined

Comment: because your `src` object don't have `src` attribute, just check this `jQuery('#frame1').html();` statement on browser console

Comment: jQuery('#frame1').html(); 
This returns undefined

Comment: `frame1` id doesn't exist in the dom

Comment: But console.log(jQuery('#frame1')); actually shows context

Comment: @mdguit - The `context` internal property of jQuery objects is **not** an element that it wraps, those are in properties with the names `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. What is the `length` of the object you get from jQuery? I'm guessing `0`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, 0. But then am I suppose to retrieve the src?

Comment: @mdguit - We need the [mcve]. We can't help you any further without it. Fundamentally, if `jQuery("#frame1").attr("src")` is returning `undefined`, it's because of one of the two caused I listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379072/jquery-attr-returns-undefined-for-iframe-element/56379194?noredirect=1#comment99358571_56379072). Perhaps you have another `id="frame1"` element in the DOM, etc. Until you reduce the problem to an MCVE that replicates the behavor, we can't help.